# how to get the result of a function as an input of another

Tags: c#, function, winforms, data-binding

I have a basic UI where the user should be able to select a geometry with one button and start the evaluation of the geometry with the another button. But I get the error: The name 'brep' does not exist in the current context

```
private void btnSelectBuilding_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyFunctions.SelectBuildingGeometry(out Rhino.Geometry.Brep brep);
}
```

```
private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyFunctions.EvaluateGeometry(brep);
}
```

Function 1:

```
public static Brep SelectBuildingGeometry(out Brep brep)
{
     ... select the geometry ...    
     return brep;
}
```

Function2:

```
public static void EvaluateGeometry(Brep brep)
{
     ... do some evaluation 
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why your `Brep SelectBuildingGeometry(out Brep brep)` method has a return Type of `Brep` and also an out parameter of the same Type? What's for? Anyway, `MyFunctions.SelectBuildingGeometry(out Rhino.Geometry.Brep brep);` set the `out` value   to a `brep` local variable that - as it appears -  is not stored anywhere, so `MyFunctions.EvaluateGeometry(brep);` won't find the `brep` reference you're trying to pass. -- You're ignoring the return value of those methods. Is it the same thing as the `out` thing?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! No, there is not a specific reason, maybe `out` is worong in this context.
Can you tell me how to fix this problem; so that `MyFunctions.EvaluateGeometry(brep);` finds the reference I want to pass?

Comment: Either using an `out` value (if actually required) or the value returned by the method, store it in a Field or dedicated class object that handles the current `Geometry.Brep` 
 selection. E.g., simplified: `private Rhino.Geometry.Brep brep = null;`. In the selector Click handler: `brep = MyFunctions.SelectBuildingGeometry();`. In the calculation Click handler: `if (brep != null) { MyFunctions.EvaluateGeometry(brep); }`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
Exactly what I was looking for :)